# replacing/re-assign pandas value with new value

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to re-assign/replace my new value, from my current

```
20000123
19850123
19880112
19951201
19850123
20190821
20000512
19850111
19670133
19850123
```

As you can see there is data with 19670133 (YYYYMMDD), which means that date is not exist since there is no month with 33 days in it.So I wanted to re assign it to the end of the month. I tried to make it to the end of the month, and it works.
But when i try to replace the old value with the new ones, it became a problem.
What I've tried to do is this :

```
for x in df_tmp_customer['date']:
    try:
        df_tmp_customer['date'] = df_tmp_customer.apply(pd.to_datetime(x), axis=1)
    except Exception:
        df_tmp_customer['date'] = df_tmp_customer.apply(pd.to_datetime(x[0:6]+"01")+ pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0), axis=1)
```

This part is the one that makes it end of the month :

```
pd.to_datetime(x[0:6]+"01")+ pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not efficient on a large dataset but can be done using [pendulum.parse()](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#parsing)

```
import pendulum


def parse_dates(x: str) -> pendulum:
    i = 0
    while ValueError:
        try:
            return pendulum.parse(str(int(x) - i)).date()
        except ValueError:
            i += 1


df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: parse_dates(x))
print(df)

         date
0  2000-01-23
1  1985-01-23
2  1988-01-12
3  1995-12-01
4  1985-01-23
5  2019-08-21
6  2000-05-12
7  1985-01-11
8  1967-01-31
9  1985-01-23
```

Answer (score 0):

For a vectorial solution, you can use:

```
# try to convert to YYYYMMDD
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')

# get rows for which conversion failed
m = date1.isna()

# try to get end of month
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[m, 'date'].str[:6], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce').add(pd.offsets.MonthEnd())

# Combine both
df['date2'] = date1.fillna(date2)
```

*NB. Assuming `df['date']` is of string dtype. If rather of integer dtype, use `df.loc[m, 'date'].floordiv(100)` in place of `df.loc[m, 'date'].str[:6]`.*

Output:

```
       date      date2
0  20000123 2000-01-23
1  19850123 1985-01-23
2  19880112 1988-01-12
3  19951201 1995-12-01
4  19850123 1985-01-23
5  20190821 2019-08-21
6  20000512 2000-05-12
7  19850111 1985-01-11
8  19670133 1967-01-31 # invalid replaced by end of month
9  19850123 1985-01-23
```